# How to evaluate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P((X_1+..+X_n)^2 + (Y_1+..+Y_n)^2 \leq n)$ by using Central limit theorem?

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

Suppose $(X_1,Y_1),(X_2,Y_2),..$ are independent, identically distributed random vectors such that
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(X_1 = 2~and~Y_1=0) &=& 1/3 \\
P(X_1 = -1~and~Y_1=\sqrt{3}) &=& 1/3 \\
P(X_1 = -1~and~Y_1=-\sqrt{3}) &=& 1/3 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Use Central limit theorem in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to evaluate
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P((X_1+..+X_n)^2 + (Y_1+..+Y_n)^2 \leq n).
$$

The theorem statement is given in the following link.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Multidimensional_CLT

Firstly, I calculate the expected value and it is a zero vector in this case, i.e, $\mu=(0,0)^t$ and the covariance matrix is $2I_2$.

By the Central limit theorem in $\mathbb{R}^2$,
$$
\sqrt{n} (\bar{X_n}) \Rightarrow N(0,2I_2).
$$
Now,
$$
P(|\sqrt{n} (\bar{X_n})|^2>1)=P((X_1+..+X_n)^2 + (Y_1+..+Y_n)^2 > n) 
$$

I understand that by applying Chebyshev's inequality I get the bound of above term.

I am little confused at this step and not really sure how to use here
$$
\sqrt{n} (\bar{X_n}) \Rightarrow N(0,2I_2).
$$

Can anyone please help me with this thought?

Comment: Forget about Chebyshev for now. Do you know what the delta method is? If so, what function maps $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n, \bar{Y}_n)$ into $(X_1 + \dots)^2/n + (Y_1 + \dots)^2/n$?

Comment: @Galton I don’t know the delta method. Could you please explain about it?

Comment: Ok in that case, $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n, \bar{Y}_n) \leadsto (X, Y)$, where $(X, Y)$ is bivariate mean-zero normal with the covariance you derived (didn't check your calculations. By the continuous-mapping theorem, $(\sqrt{n}\bar{X}_n)^2 + (\sqrt{n}\bar{Y}_n)^2\leadsto X^2 + Y^2$. What distribution is the sum of independent squared normals?

Comment: @Galton I think it is the Chisquare distribution.

Comment: Ok so the $X^2 + Y^2$ behaves like a $2 Z^2$, where $Z^2$ is chi-squared with two degrees of freedom. The limit as $n\to\infty$ of your expression is then $P(Z^2 \leq 1/2)$.